# Why can't I import the facebook SDK correctly?

Tags: android, facebook, maven, build.gradle

I added correctly as a dependency and put the central maven repository as, **there is no error in the import**! But I can't access any method as the `AppEventsLogger` only says to create the class and **NOT** import. I'm following in the footsteps of [Facebook Quick Starts](https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/).

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.morais.daniela.doctorquiz"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
}
```

log

```
16:59:02 Gradle build finished in 52 sec
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to either import com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger or use the fully qualified class name in your code.

`com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger logger;`

If you don't do this there is no way of knowing what your refering to.

Comment: Do you know why that does not appear in the "suggestions" the import?

Comment: As it's a general guide to adding the SDK to your project it doesn't specify how to add individual classes. Additionally if you type AppEventsLogger in android studio it **should** prompt you to import the class.

Comment: Meant in the previous comment: The Android Studio not suggested the import statement at the time, so it seemed there was not imported correctly. Do you know why that?

Comment: If you just hover over it then it would just say "Cannot resolve symbol", you have to click on it for the suggestion to show up.

Comment: com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger worked beautifully. Thanks!

Comment: When I try to use "import com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger;", I get the following error: "Cannot resolve symbol 'appevents'". I am using Facebook SDK 3.23.1. Is it required to have Facebook SDK 4.x in order to use Facebook Analytics?

Comment: I am finally using Facebook Analytics with Facebook SDK 3.23.1. This is the information that helped me to figure out the process for this implementation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.23.1/class/AppEventsLogger/. Also, I used "import com.facebook.AppEventsLogger;", not "import com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger;".